# adding multiple sprites of the same object to a sprite group

Tags: python, pygame

How do I create 5 character objects from a sprite group, so:

```
characters= Character()

charactergroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

#here I am trying to add five characters to the sprite group, without making 5 character objects
for k in range(5):
     charactergroup.add((characters))
```

Is it possible to do this? Or do I have to define a method for this?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.add):

> `add()`
>
> **add Sprites to this Group**
>
> `add(*sprites) -> None`
>
> Add any number of Sprites to this Group. This will only add Sprites that are not already members of the Group.
>
> Each `sprite` argument can also be a iterator containing Sprites.

Comment: How would I overcome this problem?

Comment: What problem? You simply create however many characters you want and pass them to `add`

Answer (score 0):

You would like to create 5 characters, and place them in the group?

If so, you should create 5 characters. In your snippet, you only create 1 `Character` with the name `characters`.

```
characters= Character()
```

In order to create 5 different characters you could do this:

```
for k in range(5):
    charactergroup.add(Character())
```

This would add 5 new objects of class Character to the group.

There isn't a way to add the same object to the group, since it does not make any sense.
An object has only 1 set of coordinates, so adding the same sprite, does nothing. To add more objects of the same class you can create new ones, or create a copy.